# Get Excel cell's background color using MFC

Tags: c++, excel, mfc

I am creating an application in MFC where I need to fetch Excel Cell's data along with background color.

I got below code for fetching the data but could not get cell's background color:

```
CExcelWorksheets oSheets = m_oBook.get_Sheets();
CExcelWorksheet oSheet = oSheets.get_Item( COleVariant(1) );

CExcelRange oRange = oSheet.get_UsedRange();
// Get the data
COleSafeArray saRet( oRange.get_Value2() ); // ( oRange.get_Value(covOptional) );

long nRows;
long nCols;
saRet.GetUBound( 1, &nRows );
saRet.GetUBound( 2, &nCols );

long nIndex[2];
// Loop throgth the data and report the contens
for ( int nRowCounter=1; nRowCounter <= nRows; nRowCounter++ ) {
    for ( int nColCounter=1; nColCounter <= nCols; nColCounter++ ) {
        CExcelRange rnge = oSheet.get_Range(COleVariant(TEXT("A1")), COleVariant(TEXT("A1")));

        nIndex[0] = nRowCounter;
        nIndex[1] = nColCounter;

        COleVariant covData;
        saRet.GetElement( nIndex, covData );
        CString strData;
        if ( covData.vt != VT_ERROR )
            strData = CString( covData );
        else
            strData = _T("");
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with **MFC** but in `excel-vba` you can get cell colour by: **`.Cells(<row number>, <column number>).Interior.Color`**. Can you try that in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Is the [`Interior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/interior-object-excel#) property exposed in any way?

According to the article it states:

> Use the `Interior` property to return the `Interior` object. The following example sets the color for the interior of cell A1 to red.
>
> `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

So, can you see if the `CExcelRange` object exposes this?